# How to export all databases, users and privileges of MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a server with 800 databases, over 600 users with lots of different privileges. I know I can use `mysqldump` to export all the databases but I still didnt find a safe/easy way to export all users and their privileges.

Googling, I found lots of different commands to list all users and query each user's privileges, append that to a file and keep going till last user. Is this really the safest method to export such important information? I really need to make sure the exported users/privileges are exactly as the ones in the server, I cant afford a shell command (loop) that may fail when exporting some user, or some user privilege...

And one final question: I know `mysqldump --all-databases` will not export `information_schema` and `performance_schema` (which is great) but it still exports the `mysql` database! Why? I think it's not safe to export this `mysql` database since I will probably be importing it later on a MariaDB with a more recent version! Right?

Comment: Maybe just make a backup of all the database files and copy those to the destination system.

Comment: " but it still exports the mysql database! ", know the feeling which is why I fixed it ([MDEV-23630](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-23630)), I even talked about this recently at [Percona Live 2021](https://perconaliveonline.sched.com/event/io3c/logical-mariadb-dump-system-migration-30min) and hopefully videos will be up in a few weeks. Happy to take bug reports. Happy "mysqldump --system=all" usage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MariaDB versions 10.2.37, MariaDB 10.3.28, MariaDB 10.4.18 and MariaDB 10.5.9 and above have [mysqldump --system=users](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqldump/) which will dump all CREATE USER, ROLES and GRANT statements for the users on the server.

Comment: That's great news! Reading the link you provided, I was wondering: maybe it would be easier if I backup the database `mysql` from my server e use it to restore later? Since it looks like it saves users, privileges... right?

Comment: You mentioned going from an old version of mariadb to a new version which using a backup/restore of `mysql` database will be problematic as MariaDB-10.4 changed `mysql.user` to a view. This was part of the motivation for this feature. `--system=all` does backup all relevant bits of the `mysql` database especially the users and privs.

Comment: When restoring, I had to use the "-f" flag on the mysql in order to get past the errors caused by "CREATE USER" statements in MariaDB 10.6.7.  I asked them to consider outputting CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS instead.

Comment: using `--insert-ignore` will generate `CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS` statements

Answer (score 0):

I would use [pt-show-grants](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-show-grants.html) to export users and privileges. Read that tool's documentation for usage and benefits.

Another solution to dump all schemas but the `mysql` schema: check out mysqlpump, which is a kind of successor to mysqldump. It has an option for `--exclude-database`. Also an option for `--user` that dumps users and privileges like pt-show-grants does.

Read about it:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlpump.html
- https://mysqlserverteam.com/introducing-mysqlpump/